# Combine Jetty and vert.x

Tags: jetty, equinox, vert.x

I am working on a central headless service, based on Equinox, that should support plug-ins to contribute web functionality. The head is to manage the main entry point for web requests (that is the HttpServer on port 80 and 443) and yet I would like to leave the plug-ins to use their own communication technologies.

One case I have here is vert.x so the scenario is that I initially take the connection from Jetty and then, if the url leads to the resp. plugin, pass it to the vert.x instance.

So. e.g. a call to http://example.org/vertxplugin leads to the inital http://example.org accepted by Jetty which then identifies the vertxplugin as target passing the resp. connection.

Currently I do not see how such a scenario can be realized - as I see only examples of vert.x generating the HttpServer or jetty generating the HttpServer.

Additionally is something like

```
// create the websocket
vertx.createSockJSServer(httpServer).bridge(config, inOK, outOK);
```

where the httpServer mentioned here is Jetty, possible??

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I cant understand correctly your question but if you wish handle the data with jetty and then call vertx, you can use vertx embedded, then communicate across eventbus your jetty app and your vertx verticles, here is a link but maybe you could ask in the vertx google group for better guidance http://vertx.io/embedding_manual.html

Comment: Thats what I want to do! The examples on embedding_manual do, however, again show a netserver that was created by vert.x. So my stack is
NET <---> HTTP | JETTY <----> VERT.X

is this possible in a manual embedding? Does it leave me the full power (polyglot etc.) of vert.x?

Comment: yep,sure,it's possible, ask in the vertx google group for better guidance..